# AngularJS application is not loading in safari browser (<10.1versions) after minification

Tags: angularjs, webpack, safari

AngularJS application is not loading in safari browser below version 10. This issue occurs only after minifying the code using WEBPACK and only in safari browser (<10.1 versions). It works, Above 10 versions of safari and other browsers after minification.  Error in safari browser looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Safari doesn't fully support ES6 features until 10.3. The `const` keyword is an ES6 feature. If you want to support Safari version earlier than 10 you must not use any ES6 features, unless you use a shim or transpiler

Comment: To remove ES6 syntax try BabelJS compiler

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash i removed all the ES6 feature and tried. But the second error which says "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xce.app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'xce.app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." is NOT RESOLVED.

Comment: show your controller setup. are you using the angular.module('name').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope)]); format?